# Cannot link Form1.vb to .rldc from the Design View. Missing from VS2017 Community?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, rdlc

I recently downgraded from VS 2015 Professional to VS 2017 Community (not by Choice). When I start a Visual Basic reporting Application I go through all of my steps. Dataset > DB > Table Adapter > Make the .rldc and then Link it on the Form from the little "triangle" on the upper right hand corner.
[image: Form1.vb]

For some reason it's not there. Am I missing something? I just want to be able to link it so I dont get the "Report Definition not Defined" when debugging. Is it a toolbox item that came stock in Professionals Application Form when it creates the project?

I deleted and reinstalled all of the references for `Microsoft.ReportViewer.` and that did not fix it. The RDLC is there so there **is** something to link.

[image: RDLC Created with Table adapter and Columns/Data]

Reinstalling 2015 Professional (or 2017 Professional) is not an option. Can anyone help?

**Fixed**: Working Versions of NuGet
[image]

You also need to Erase this Line of Code and it should work.
[image]

**Working Test**
[image]

Comment: I don't really use that control myself but I did do a little bit of research on the subject recently when someone else was having an issue.  I found that the two most recent versions of the NuGet package didn't work and I had to go back to a version ending with ".99"

Comment: I didn't see  a .99. I rolled back to a few other previous Versions and they broke on a "Mismatch". I found that ReportViewerControl 150.1358 and ReportViewer 11.0.3366.16 worked. **But** I had to get rid of this Token for `Me.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.BearerToken = Nothing` to get the Form to display the control. This is Fixed.